# Spark: FlatMap and CountVectorizer pipeline

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, countvectorizer

I working on the pipeline and try to split the column value before passing it to `CountVectorizer`.

For this purpose I made a custom Transformer.

```
class FlatMapTransformer(override val uid: String)
  extends Transformer {
  /**
   * Param for input column name.
   * @group param
   */
  final val inputCol = new Param[String](this, "inputCol", "The input column")
  final def getInputCol: String = $(inputCol)

  /**
   * Param for output column name.
   * @group param
   */
  final val outputCol = new Param[String](this, "outputCol", "The output column")
  final def getOutputCol: String = $(outputCol)

  def setInputCol(value: String): this.type = set(inputCol, value)
  def setOutputCol(value: String): this.type = set(outputCol, value)

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("FlatMapTransformer"))

  private val flatMap: String => Seq[String] = { input: String =>
    input.split(",")
  }

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): SplitString = defaultCopy(extra)

  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    val flatMapUdf = udf(flatMap)
    dataset.withColumn($(outputCol), explode(flatMapUdf(col($(inputCol)))))
  }

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    val dataType = schema($(inputCol)).dataType
    require(
      dataType.isInstanceOf[StringType],
      s"Input column must be of type StringType but got ${dataType}")
    val inputFields = schema.fields
    require(
      !inputFields.exists(_.name == $(outputCol)),
      s"Output column ${$(outputCol)} already exists.")

    DataTypes.createStructType(
      Array(
        DataTypes.createStructField($(outputCol), DataTypes.StringType, false)))
  }
}
```

The code seems legit, but when I try to chain it with other operation the problem occurs. Here is my pipeline:

```
val train = reader.readTrainingData()

val cat_features = getFeaturesByType(taskConfig, "categorical")
val num_features = getFeaturesByType(taskConfig, "numeric")
val cat_ohe_features = getFeaturesByType(taskConfig, "categorical", Some("ohe"))
val cat_features_string_index = cat_features.
  filter { feature: String => !cat_ohe_features.contains(feature) }

val catIndexer = cat_features_string_index.map {
  feature =>
    new StringIndexer()
      .setInputCol(feature)
      .setOutputCol(feature + "_index")
      .setHandleInvalid("keep")
}

    val flatMapper = cat_ohe_features.map {
      feature =>
        new FlatMapTransformer()
          .setInputCol(feature)
          .setOutputCol(feature + "_transformed")
    }

    val countVectorizer = cat_ohe_features.map {
      feature =>

        new CountVectorizer()
          .setInputCol(feature + "_transformed")
          .setOutputCol(feature + "_vectorized")
          .setVocabSize(10)
    }


// val countVectorizer = cat_ohe_features.map {
//   feature =>
//
//     val flatMapper = new FlatMapTransformer()
//       .setInputCol(feature)
//       .setOutputCol(feature + "_transformed")
// 
//     new CountVectorizer()
//       .setInputCol(flatMapper.getOutputCol)
//       .setOutputCol(feature + "_vectorized")
//       .setVocabSize(10)
// }

val cat_features_index = cat_features_string_index.map {
  (feature: String) => feature + "_index"
}

val count_vectorized_index = cat_ohe_features.map {
  (feature: String) => feature + "_vectorized"
}

val catFeatureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(cat_features_index)
  .setOutputCol("cat_features")

val oheFeatureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(count_vectorized_index)
  .setOutputCol("cat_ohe_features")

val numFeatureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(num_features)
  .setOutputCol("num_features")

val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("cat_features", "num_features", "cat_ohe_features_vectorized"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

val pipelineStages = catIndexer ++ flatMapper ++ countVectorizer ++
  Array(
    catFeatureAssembler,
    oheFeatureAssembler,
    numFeatureAssembler,
    featureAssembler)

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(pipelineStages)
pipeline.fit(dataset = train)
```

Running this code, I receive an error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "my_ohe_field_trasformed" does not exist.`

```
[info]  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "from_expdelv_areas_transformed" does not exist.

[info]  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:266)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:266)

[info]  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)

[info]  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)

[info]  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:265)

[info]  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnTypes(SchemaUtils.scala:56)

[info]  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:75)

[info]  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.validateAndTransformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:123)

[info]  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.transformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:188)
```

When I uncomment the `stringSplitter` and `countVectorizer` the error is raised in my Transformer

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "my_ohe_field" does not exist.` at 
`val dataType = schema($(inputCol)).dataType`

Result of calling `pipeline.getStages`:

```
strIdx_3c2630a738f0

strIdx_0d76d55d4200

FlatMapTransformer_fd8595c2969c

FlatMapTransformer_2e9a7af0b0fa

cntVec_c2ef31f00181

cntVec_68a78eca06c9

vecAssembler_a81dd9f43d56

vecAssembler_b647d348f0a0

vecAssembler_b5065a22d5c8

vecAssembler_d9176b8bb593
```

I might follow the wrong way. Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FlatMapTransformer #transform` is incorrect, your kind of dropping/ignoring all other columns when you select only on `outputCol`

### please modify your method to -

```scala
 override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
     val flatMapUdf = udf(flatMap)
    dataset.withColumn($(outputCol), explode(flatMapUdf(col($(inputCol)))))
  }
```

Also, Modify your `transformSchema` to check input column first before checking its datatype-

```scala
 override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
require(schema.names.contains($(inputCol)), "inputCOl is not there in the input dataframe")
//... rest as it is
}
```

### Update-1 based on comments

1. PLease modify the `copy` method (Though it's not the cause for exception you facing)-

```
override def copy(extra: ParamMap): FlatMapTransformer = defaultCopy(extra)
```

2. please note that the `CountVectorizer` takes the column having columns of type `ArrayType(StringType, true/false)` and since the `FlatMapTransformer` output columns becomes the input of `CountVectorizer`, you need to make sure output column of `FlatMapTransformer` must be of `ArrayType(StringType, true/false)`. I think, this is not the case, your code today is as following-

```
  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    val flatMapUdf = udf(flatMap)
    dataset.withColumn($(outputCol), explode(flatMapUdf(col($(inputCol)))))
  }
```

The `explode` functions converts the `array<string>` to `string`, so the output of the transformer becomes `StringType`. you may wanted to change this code to-

```
  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    val flatMapUdf = udf(flatMap)
    dataset.withColumn($(outputCol), flatMapUdf(col($(inputCol))))
  }
```

3. modify `transformSchema` method to output `ArrayType(StringType)`

```
 override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
      val dataType = schema($(inputCol)).dataType
      require(
        dataType.isInstanceOf[StringType],
        s"Input column must be of type StringType but got ${dataType}")
      val inputFields = schema.fields
      require(
        !inputFields.exists(_.name == $(outputCol)),
        s"Output column ${$(outputCol)} already exists.")

      schema.add($(outputCol), ArrayType(StringType))
    }
```

4. change vector assembler to this-

```
val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(Array("cat_features", "num_features", "cat_ohe_features"))
      .setOutputCol("features")
```

I tried to execute your pipeline on dummy dataframe, it worked well. Please refer [this gist](https://gist.github.com/skale1990/26448400c7655543f9e1177dd17763bf#file-problemsolvertest-scala-L776) for full code.

Comment: Thanks for a swift reply. Unfortunately the problem remains `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "my_ohe_field_trasformed" does not exist.`

Comment: full stacktrace please?

Comment: are you sure you added `FlatMapTransformer`?

Comment: check `pipeline.getStages`, i'm sure `FlatMapTransformer` isn't there

Comment: sure I did. I printed out the `pipeline.getStages` and `FlatMapTransformer` exist there

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the late reply - I just reached the computer. I'll to execute - hope that would help. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.